# How to link lapack with php

Tags: php, lapack

I need to solve a linear equation so I installed Lapack

```
svn co https://icl.cs.utk.edu/svn/lapack-dev/lapack/trunk lapack
cd lapack
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -D BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON -D LAPACKE=ON ../
make 
sudo make install
```

I followed this steps and tried

```
 <?php
    $a = array(
    array( 1.44,  -7.84,  -4.39,   4.53),
    array(-9.96,  -0.28,  -3.24,   3.83),
    array(-7.55,   3.24,   6.27,  -6.64),
    array( 8.34,   8.09,   5.28,   2.06),
    array( 7.08,   2.52,   0.74,  -2.47),
    array(-5.45,  -5.70,  -1.19,   4.70),
    );

    $b = array(
    array( 8.58,   9.35),
    array( 8.26,  -4.43),
    array( 8.48,  -0.70),
    array(-5.28,  -0.26),
    array( 5.72,  -7.36),
    array( 8.93,  -2.52),           
    );

   $result = Lapack::leastSquaresByFactorisation($a, $b);
   var_dump($result);
   ?>
```

this code to Test it , But its saying lapack class is not defined
Please help

Comment: Have you change `php.ini` to load this module and restart apache/nginx?

Comment: No, How to load this module using php.ini and also i found this in their page.
http://php.net/manual/en/lapack.configuration.php

thanks

Comment: Most likely you have to refer here https://github.com/ianbarber/php-lapack